# How to disable Intellij warning - Field injection is not recommended

Tags: intellij-idea

How to disable the below warning (`Field injection is not recommended`)in Intellij idea settings?

[image]

Note:

Do not start advising prefer Constructor injection over field injection etc. This is Spring.

Comment: Click on the three dots on the right!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open up IntelliJ preferences
2. Go to editor
3. Go to inspections
4. Find `non recommended 'field' injections`
5. Disable it

Comment: where do you see it.? under which category?

Comment: It's under the list of `Editor`. You can also search in preferences: `Inspections`.

Comment: got it. Thanks.

Comment: @RamPrakash Glad it was helpful. Please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Stackoverflow says I shoudl wait for X minutes to accept.